# Error: got unexpected status: FORBIDDEN -- config update for existing channel did not pass initial checks: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm using Fabric 2.0 binaries and following this tutorial link https://github.com/orderstack/hyperledger-fabric-v2-starter

When i go into

```
cd network/scripts
```

and then enter this command

```
./network.sh up createChannel -ca
```

I get this error.

```
Error: got unexpected status: FORBIDDEN -- config update for existing channel did not pass initial checks: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any data left from a previous run?
Also - why not use the test-network from fabric-samples?